# 'this' keyword in Javascript inheritence chain

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I have a function named Car as a supertype

```js
let Car = function(){};
Car.prototype = {
    constructor: Car,
    numWheel: 4,
    numLight : 2,
    describe = function () {
        console.log(`This car is ${this.name} produced in ${this.version} `);
    }
}
```

I want to make a subtype constructor inherit from it, and make an instance from this constructor

```
let Honda = function (name, version) {
    this.name = name;
    this.version = version;
}
Honda.prototype = Object.create(Car.prototype);
Honda.prototype = {
    constructor: Honda
}
let civic = new Honda('civic', 2015);
```

The question i want to make is where the 'this' in supertype point to in the subtype object here. When I try to call the function

```
civic.describe;
```

It appear an error.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer

Why 'this' keyword cannot be inherited?

Comment: `describe = function`??? What is this suppose to do? Apart from that typo, `numWheel` and `numLight` should be a part of constructor and not prototype. Properties on prototype are shared across objects

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I mean, it should be `describe: function`

Comment: Oh. But when i changed it back to `describe: function` as you said, it appear undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code:

1. The way you assign the function to the object property (`describe = function() { /* ... */}`), is syntactically invalid.
2. You reassign to the `Honda` prototype, overwriting what you had previously assigned using `Object.create()`.

This snippet solves both issues by correctly initializing the object and using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

```js
let Car = function() {};
Car.prototype = {
  constructor: Car,
  numWheel: 4,
  numLight: 2,
  describe: function() {
    console.log(`This car is ${this.name} produced in ${this.version} `);
  }
}


let Honda = function(name, version) {
  this.name = name;
  this.version = version;
}
Honda.prototype = Object.assign({}, Car.prototype, {
  constructor: Honda
});

let civic = new Honda('civic', 2015);
civic.describe();
```

Comment: It's strange. `Object.create()` is just supposed to set the prototype of the object `Honda`, and I didn't touch the prototype parts of it except for assigning the constructor property

Comment: Consider `prototype` as another property. You are assigning it twice. What will this property hold at the end?

Comment: @Robby, it should be `Object.assign({}, Car.prototype, { constructor: Honda })` instead. `civic.constructor.name` is returning `Car` in your code

Comment: I got it. It turns out that I can keep using the `Object.create` method as long as I won't reassign it. Thank a lot